# How to create cross database communication via service broker

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I do not need examples. I have a lot of them and I can create the objects with the results I needed. I just want to understand the service broker workflow. I need to send the message from InitiatorDB to TargetDB. Do not need any responses back (if only the ones to handle dialogues properly). 
There are few questions for me I do not understand:

1. On [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166123(v=sql.105).aspx) they are stating:

> You create an identical contract/message type in each database that participates in
>   a conversation

Does that mean that I **MUST** create contracts/messages with identical names on both databases?

2. How does the service broker where to send the message? I am providing FROM_Service and TO_Service. Service is server object? Not database? But I can create identical services on multiply databases on the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the following. It explains how service broker is able to move the messages between two databases.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166057(v=sql.105).aspx

Also if you follow the link to "Service Broker Routing" this should give you a good idea of what it does.